# Get user input at startup

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have a script i need to run after installation at first boot, that ask user for hostname and set new hostname. What is best way to do it?
Right now i do it this way:

rc.local

```
openvt -s -w /opt/post_install_script
```

post_install_script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW_HOSTNAME="$1"
echo -n "Please enter new hostname: "
read NEW_HOSTNAME < /dev/tty
doing other stuff..
```

Its work ok on Ubuntu 12 but don't wait for user input and continue boot on Ubuntu 16.

I have read about systemd systemd-ask-password but its doesn't work too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Create file **/etc/systemd/system/renamepc.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hostname configuration
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=nss-user-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create file **/opt/script**:

```
#!/bin/bash       
NEW_HOSTNAME=$(systemd-ask-password "Please enter new hostname: " --echo)
change hostname code...
```

Change script permission **chmod u+x /opt/test**